# Manter valores quando se usa o history.back

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho uma pagina de pesquisa que é toda em ajax que esta funcionando legal, tipo o site do trivago. So que quando eu altero os valores dos campos e depois eu escolho um dos itens da resposta eu carrego uma nova pagina com os detalhes do item ai se eu clico no botão do navegar de Voltar ou uso o comando do javascript history.back() ele volta para a pagina da pesquisa mais sem os valores que eu tinha alterado.

Tem como guardar os valores em algum lugar para que quando ele recarregue a pagina via cache ele use estes valores?

Obrigado

Comment: Você pode usar sessionStorage/localStorage para transitar os dados.

Comment: @Laerte valeu pela dica deu certinho. Muito Obrigado

Comment: Eu até postarei um exemplo que bom que deu certo! ;)